# Does keras-tokenizer perform the task of lemmatization and stemming?

Tags: keras, nlp, tokenize, stemming, lemmatization

Does keras tokenizer provide the functions such as stemming and lemmetization? If it does, then how is it done? Need an intuitive understanding. Also, what does `text_to_sequence` do in that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be some confusion what a *tokenizer* does respectively what *tokenization* is. Tokenization splits a string into smaller entities such as words or single characters. Therefore, these are also referred  to as *tokens*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) provides a nice example:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` becomes:

```
<sentence>
  <word>The</word>
  <word>quick</word>
  ...
  <word>dog</word>
</sentence>
```

Lemmatization (*grouping together the inflected forms of a word* -> [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)) or stemming (*process of reducing inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their word stem* -> [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)) is something you do during preprocessing. Tokenization can be a part of a preprocessing process before or after (or both) lemmatization and stemming.

Anyhow, Keras is no framework for fully fletched text-preprocessing. Hence, you feed already cleaned, lemmatized etc. data into Keras. ***Regarding your first question: No, Keras does not provide such functionallity like lemmatization or stemming.***

What Keras understands under *Text preprocessing* like [here in the docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/) is the functionallity to prepare data in order to be fed to a Keras-model (like a Sequential model). This is for example why the [Keras-Tokenizer](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#Tokenizer) does this:

> This class allows to vectorize a text corpus, by turning each text
>   into either a sequence of integers (each integer being the index of a
>   token in a dictionary) or into a vector where the coefficient for each
>   token could be binary, based on word count, based on tf-idf...

By for example vectorizing your input strings and transforming them into numeric data you can feed them as input to a, in case of Keras, neural network.

What `text_to_sequence` means can be extracted from this: *[...]sequence of integers (each integer being the index of a token in a dictionary)[...]*.
This means that your former strings can afterwards be a sequence (e.g. array) of numeric integers instead of actual words.

Regarding this you should also take a look on what Keras Sequential models are (e.g. [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)) since they take seuqences as input.

Additionally, `text_to_word_sequence()` ([docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#text_to_word_sequence)) also provides such tokenization, but does not vectorize your data into numeric vectors and returns an array of your tokenized strings.

> Converts a text to a sequence of words (or tokens).